substitution in proofs with recursive formulas
The following problem and partial solution are from Richard Bird's Thinking Functionally with Haskell (pp 132-133, 139)
given
foldl f e (x:xs) = foldl f (f e x) xs
foldl f e [] = e

Prove foldl (@) e xs = foldr (<>) e xs for all finite lists xs provided that

(x <> y) @ z = x <> (y @ z)
e @ x = x <> e

induction case (left-hand side):
foldl (@) e (x:xs) = {def foldl} 
foldl (@) (e @ x) xs = {proviso 2} 
foldl (@) (x <> e) xs

This is obviously not the last step of the proof, but it's the source of my question: Because e is expanded recursively by foldl, it seems like its definition depends on the stage of the recursion, and therefore it's not clear to me that e @ x = x <> e is always a valid substitution. Above in foldl (@) (e @ x) xs, argument e of foldl takes on the value of e @ x, so I would think that proviso 2 can't be applied -- to make the substitution it would need to be (e @ x) @ x

EDIT
Here's the complete proof



left hand
right hand




foldl (@) e (x:xs) = {def foldl}
foldr (<>) e (x:xs) = {def foldr}


foldl (@) (e @ x) xs = {proviso 2}
x <> foldr (<>) e xs = {induction}


foldl (@) (x <> e) xs
x <> foldl (@) e xs




The two sides have simplified to different results. We need another induction hypothesis:
foldl (@) (x <> y) xs = x <> foldl (@) y xs
The base case is trivial. For the inductive case




left hand
right hand




foldl (@) (x <> y) (z:zs) = {def foldl}
x <> foldl (@) y (z:zs) = {def foldl}


foldl (@) ((x <> y) @ z) zs = {proviso 1}
x <> foldl (@) (y @ z) zs


foldl (@) (x <> (y @ z)) zs = {induction}



x <> foldl (@) (y @ z) zs





I don't understand what you mean by "e is expanded recursively by foldl". Given e @ x = x <> e (there is no need to question it) it follows that foldl (@) (e @ x) xs is foldl (@) (x <> e) xs.

If e is meant to be a fixed value, that property does not seem to be directly provable by induction, since the second argument of foldl changes as you discovered. I wonder if e is instead meant to be "just another variable" like y, so proviso 2 and the induction hypothesis have an implicit quantifier "for all values e ..." on top.

This can be proved for e fixed in the statement of the theorem (i.e., with the identity e @ x = x <> e holding for all x but only a specific e), but it's quite a bit more complicated than the part of the proof you've shown.  I don't have a copy of the original source, so I don't know how much additional guidance the solution gives.
Anyway, I found it helpful to first prove an intermediate result:
forall y, z, xs: foldl (@) (y <> z) xs = y <> foldl (@) z xs       -- (A)

This can be proved inductively on xs.  The base case is:
foldl (@) (y <> z) []
= y <> z                    -- foldl definition
= y <> foldl (@) z []       -- foldl definition

The inductive case is:
foldl (@) (y <> z) (x:xs)
= foldl (@) ((y <> z) @ x) xs     -- foldl definition
= foldl (@) (y <> (z @ x)) xs     -- assumption #1
= y <> foldl (@) (z @ x) xs       -- inductive assumption for z: = z @ x
= y <> foldl (@) z (x:xs)         -- foldl definition

So, (A) is established.
Now, we can turn to the desired result:
forall xs. foldl (@) e xs = foldr (<>) e xs         -- (B)

which can also be proved inductively.
The base case is:
foldl (@) e []
= e                          -- foldl definition
= foldr (<>) e []            -- foldr definition

The inductive step is:
foldl (@) e (x:xs)
= foldl (@) (e @ x) xs            -- foldl definition
= foldl (@) (x <> e) xs           -- assumption #2 for fixed e only
= x <> foldl (@) e xs             -- intermediate result (A) specialized to z := e
= x <> foldr (<>) e xs            -- inductive assumption
= foldr (<>) e (x:xs)             -- definition of foldr


I'm not asking for such a proof, but do you think it's possible to establish that the theorem holds for all values e as @chi suggests?

To be clear, the proof establishes the theorem for all e, it just does so with a weaker assumption #2 than @chi is suggesting.  In other words, you're asking if you can replace an assumption with a stronger assumption (i.e., replacing "P(e)" with "forall e'. P(e')" for some predicate P), and have the theorem still hold, and the answer is, "of course!"  The theorem can be proved with the same proof as before, you just don't use the full strength of the revised assumption.

I agree. My statement was of the form "if Hp(e) holds for all e, then Th(e) holds for all e". Instead K.A.Buhr proved "for all e, if Hp(e) then Th(e)" which is stronger. Unrelated: I do wonder if the intended solution requires the solver to find the auxiliary property on their own. If so, I'd consider that a relatively advanced exercise, requiring a certain degree of creativity and skill. I don't think it is something that can be easily solved by everyone without hints.

I've added the rest of the proof.
